# Issue using FastF1 API

Tags: python, api, download, syntax-error

I wanted to play around with the fastf1 API as I am a massive F1 fan. I found a few examples to start getting used to the datasets etc but I got stuck at the very first step. I posted two photos of issues I have faced and I dont understand how to solve them. [Image one of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWawE.png) [image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48fpU.png)

(I am quite new to python)

the following are the tutorials I am following

1. https://medium.com/@jaspervhat/how-to-analyze-formula-1-data-with-python-a-beginners-tutorial-23087c4eef1d
2. https://theoehrly.github.io/Fast-F1/examples/basics.html

EDIT - I got the cache issue sorted but image one based of tutorial link 2 still doesnt make sense

Comment: Well the second image tells you that you need to create a `cache` directory to open it, so do that with the `os` module. Python tracebacks are normally very descriptive...from the first image I cannot tell where the error is coming from so more data on the issue is needed

Comment: I will try create the cache. The first image is all the error I have got. Its based of the link 2 i posted. I literally did what it said, downloaded Fastf1 and then wrote the code as they said but got the error stated. Which is why I am so confused

Comment: I have just re done the code and seem to get a 
'UserWarning: Request returned: 403' 
Does that help in anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an issue due to the older version of [fastf1](https://theoehrly.github.io/Fast-F1/).
[image]

Please try upgrading the library version or you need to update the code based on the package changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that your issue should be fixed by now, but you can give the path of your venv.
It works for me, for example, you can do this.

```
cache = ff1.Cache.enable_cache('Path/to/venv')
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Before I was getting the Cache error until I added the `~/` before the `Documents` in the cache enable function. IT IS VERY IMPORTANT.

I am also a COMPLETE python noob and was struggling with this. Putting a more complete answer for how I solved this -

FYI - did this on a MacBook Pro M1 Pro

**Install python first**

[Follow the instructions here](https://www.python.org) if you didn't already

**Install pip**

`python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`

Then upgraded it. IDK if this is redundant but IIRC I actually had to run it / saw it upgrade

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

**Create a folder for the work**

I chose `~/Documents/` as a place to put my folder per the tutorial, and also named the folder `Formula1_python`. The name can be whatever you want but if you're a noob like me just call it this so you can copy pasta later.

**Install the virtual environment**

I'm using the Terminal App on my Mac. Launch it and type in the following:

`pip install virtualenv`

You shouldn't see any errors above. Navigate to the correct folder to finish the installation.

`cd Documents/Formula1_python`

After that, run the below

`virtualenv venv`

If you open up the Formula1_python folder you should see a new folder called `venv`. Success! Now let's activate it(?)

`source venv/bin/activate`

**And now install fastf1 and notebook**

`pip install fastf1`

Now we're starting to cook. You'll see some progress bars on the download and installation.

Now let's install Jupyter Notebook for the next step

`pip install notebook`

LET IT COOK! Oh it's done cooking? Now we can launch...

**Jupyter Notebook**

Launch it by running:

`jupyter-notebook`

By the way we need to create a cache folder in the correct location. Go into the `~/Documents/Formula1_python/venv/` with your Finder. Create a new folder within the `venv` folder called `cache`.

A new webpage should have launched. Look in the upper right and click `New` and select `Python`

Now follow the instructions from [this medium post](https://medium.com/towards-formula-1-analysis/how-to-analyze-formula-1-data-with-python-a-beginners-tutorial-23087c4eef1d) started at "Getting Started with Fast F1". I realize I repeated some of the stuff from this post but honestly these notes are mostly for me.

**Syntax for the Cache**

This next part got me scratching my head for a few hours and I hate it. But the syntax is as follows:

`import fastf1`
`fastf1.Cache.enable_cache('~/Documents/Formula1_python/venv')`

Before I was getting the Cache error until I added the `~/` before the `Documents`. IT IS VERY IMPORTANT. GLHF out there.